# Calling cypress-firebase's cy.login() does not result in logged-in user

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, cypress

I am using Cypress for end-to-end testing an application, together with the [`cypress-firebase`](https://github.com/prescottprue/cypress-firebase) package. I followed the official setup instructions (using TypeScript, and the Firebase Web SDK version 9 with the `compat` mode).

In my tests, calling `cy.login()` seems to work as expected in that Cypress logs that the `createCustomToken` task successfully performs two HTTP `POST`s with status code 200 each.

However, when visiting a page of the application afterwards, no user is logged in. In the application, the login status is supposed to be detected using Firebase's `onAuthStateChanged` function. It seems that `cy.login()` never triggers `onAuthStateChanged`, though.

My best guess is that maybe the `auth` instances used by `cypress-firebase` and the application code are not the same?! Is there a way to confirm this, or could there be another reason?

Happy to provide further information if it may help.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was indeed related to `auth` instances not matching: The application was using a named instance, whereas the `initializeApp` code in Cypress was not naming the app (and thus relying in an app instance named `[DEFAULT]`).

Fortunately, `cypress-firebase` [has support for named apps](https://github.com/prescottprue/cypress-firebase#named-app-support):

```js
const namedApp = firebase.initializeApp(fbConfig, "app_name");

attachCustomCommands({ Cypress, cy, firebase, app: namedApp });
```